# How to print value for the specific registers in GDB?

Tags: c, arm, gdb

Does anybody know how to print content of the scr_el3 register via GDB?
It is for the ARM platform.

The dump of assembler code is given for example below:

```
   0x0000000000004394 <+20>:    msr     scr_el3, x18
   0x0000000000004398 <+24>:    msr     spsr_el3, x16
   0x000000000000439c <+28>:    msr     elr_el3, x17
```

I've tried:

```
(gdb) print $pc
$10 = (void (*)()) 0x43a0 <el3_exit+32>
(gdb) print $spsr_el3
$11 = void
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: does `(gdb) info all-registers` work?

Comment: No, it will give a lot of registers with mysterious names, but there is no spsr_el3 register.

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently out of office so I cannot try on my devboards. Hopefully someone else will step in :-)

Comment: I got it. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: BTW, which arm core?

Comment: The cores are ARM Cortex-A57 and ARM Cortex-A53.